# NSNumbers changing

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

I have an array of NSNumbers I am saving into Core Data entities.

I have set their NSNumber property I want to set to Integer64.

On some of the numbers I get strange results and am wondering if it is a type issue.

I have a temporary object I fill with data that gets extracted into the Core-Data type object on creation.

e.g. `[cachableObject setValue:tempObject.number forKey:@"number"];`

I place two log statements, one above, the other below this line.

```
NSLog(@"tempObject.number is %@", tempObject.number);
[cachableObject setValue:tempObject.number forKey:@"number"];
NSLog(@"cachableObject.number is %@", cachableObject.number);
```

This logs the following on the two incorrect occurrences(so far):

```
tempObject.number is 14047556750440521185
cachableObject.number is -4399187323269030431

tempObject.number is 12267813409388115511
cachableObject.number is -6178930664321436105
```

What is causing this problem? On other numbers, the numbers dont change.

Comment: Signed integer overflow - your numbers are too big. You need to use unsigned integers.

Comment: I thought so, but unsure on the type to set for this attribute in the Core-Data model.

Comment: do you need to do math with these numbers?  if you can afford to give up some speed (and space), strings might be less headache.

Comment: If you can afford to give up some accuracy, use doubles. Your numbers can then be pretty much as big as you like but will be rounded to about 15 significant figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
14047556750440521185 = 0xC2F2F26FF825DDE1
```

is greater than `2^63 - 1` and exceeds the range of a *signed* 64-bit integer number. You can store it in a *unsigned* 64-bit integer, but when interpreted as *signed* number, the result is `-4399187323269030431`.

Core Data uses signed 64-bit numbers for an `Integer 64` attribute, and even if you assign it a unsigned 64-bit number, the value is internally stored as signed 64-bit number.

If you know that the value is an unsigned number, you can use

```
unsigned long long x = [cachableObject.number unsignedLongLongValue];
```

to convert it to an unsigned value again.

Comment: Thanks. Any non conflicting numerical hashing techniques you could recommend?

Comment: All the values are signed before caching. The overflowing ones return as unsigned ints.

Comment: @Helium3: I am sorry, but I do not understand your last comment. What caching are you speaking of?

Comment: @Helium3: About *hashing*, you would have to show for what you want to compute a hash. Perhaps that is a different question, unrelated to Core Data.

Comment: Pretty much any hash can be considered numerical. You get a string of bits, and while it's common to represent them as hex strings it's not inherent to the hashing process. Doing math with hash values doesn't make a lot of sense so, what is it you actually need to do here?

Comment: @Helium3: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if you need more information. Otherwise it would be good if you "accept" the answer.